# Why do I get a Script Documents Tree under my solution when running it?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I run my solution, when certain parts of code are run such as logging in, I noticed that a node called "Script Documents" shows up under the solution node.  Under script documents, it says Windows Internet Explorer and under that, various files show up, such as plain text files just named "anonymous code", javascript files, ScriptResource.asx?.... etc.  This is happening in visual studio 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does this because it is in JS debugging mode. You're seeing the interpreted script of the page

Comment: How do I get it out of JS debugging mode or does it go away when you usually push to a live server?

Comment: You'll only get it when the VS debugger is attached to IE, so if you aren't interested in debugging JS or whatnot, you can safely ignore it.

Comment: As an addendum, if you don't want VS to attach to IE, you can manually go to Debug -> attach to process -> aspnet_wp.exe (for IIS sites) / Web Development server (port xxx) (for cassini)

Comment: This is confirmed bug in VS 2019 (still) https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/351537/provide-a-way-to-prevent-the-script-documents-fold.html